# Certificado Https para localhost. No logro activarlo correctamente. java 8 y apache tomcat 8

Tags: https, localhost, certificado

Hola junto con saludar tengo el siguiente problema...
Llevo muchas horas investigando y todavía no logro resolverlo.

Estoy trabajando Con **java 8 y apache tomcat 8.**

**Primero mostrare los pasos que realice** y **así aprovecho de aportar información** para la gente que no sepa y a la misma vez **para que me digan si me falto algo**.

***Mi objetivo es lograr instalar un certificado para trabajar con https como localhost**, ya que estoy desarrollando una aplicación pwa(tengo entendido que esto necesita si o si https)

EL primero paso es como se genera con keytool de java:

abrir CMD como administrador:

[image: Generar key]

La key se genera correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\conf
en el archivo server.xml  agrego lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ahora procedo al siguiente paso que es instalar el certificado: 
Siguiente, siguiente, etc.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se genera el certificado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clic derecho en instalar:
Instalar certificado -> Equipo Local -> Colocar todos los certificados en el siguiente almacén -> Entidades de certificación raíz de confianza -> siguiente y finalizar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Reinicio tomcat y entro a la aplicación.

https://localhost:8443/proyectopwa/servlet/com.proyecto.home

pero el certificado dice que no es valido.

**Este es el problema que tengo, como se puede resolver?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Saludos cordiales y gracias.**

Comment: Puede que te falte añadir en el certificado un nombre alternativo.

Comment: Te refieres a la primera imagen? eso se hace ahí ? y como seria ? gracias.

Consuta: La llave que genere con keytool también debo importarla con linea de comando ?